# SQL QUERY- multiple COUNT returns wrong (same) results when using in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by

I will simplfy this:

I have two SQL expressions which works OK:

First:

```
select count(*) as number1
 from T1
where DATE1>'2012-01-01' and DATE2<'2012-12-31'
```

Result:13

```
select  count(*) as number2 
from T1
where DATE3>DATE2 and CURDATE()>DATE2
```

Result:5

But when I try to insert those two COUNTS in GROUP BY I am getting as resulyt always 13!!!

```
SELECT NAME,
 COUNT(case when DATE1>'2012-01-01' and DATE2<'2012-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) as number1, 
COUNT (case when (DATE3>DATE2 and CURDATE()>DATE2) then 1 else 0 end) as number 2
from T1
```

I am getting as result:

```
NAME  NUMBER1  NUMBER2
A       5         5
B       4         4
C       4         4
```

But I should get:

```
NAME  NUMBER1  NUMBER2
A       5         4
B       4         0
C       4         1
```

So that SUM of columns be 13 and 5 like in first two queries . What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COUNT(expression)` counts not null expressions. You can modify your query by changing the `ELSE 0` to `ELSE NULL` or by removing it (the `ELSE NULL` is implied at `CASE` expressions):

```
SELECT name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN date1 > '2012-01-01' AND date2 < '2012-12-31' 
              THEN 1 END
         ) AS number1, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN date3 > date2 AND CURDATE() > date2 
              THEN 1 END
         ) AS number2
FROM T1 
GROUP BY name ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use count here.Use Sum. If you want to use the count then put null in else instead of 0

Comment: sorry how do ypou mean with SUM? I must count them not to summarize them. Thank you

Comment: Count will not count the null values but will count anything which is not null that is why your count is counting values for all qualified rows.So try to change the else clause with null instead of 0 and see the results.

Comment: @GulliMeel you should edit your current answer and expand on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT NAME,
(select count(*) from T1 where DATE1>'2012-01-01' and DATE2<'2012-12-31') AS number1,
(select count(*) from T1 where DATE3>DATE2 and CURDATE()>DATE2) AS number2
FROM T1
GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: shouldn't i do grouping also?

Comment: yes, sorry, i didn't complete the statement originally.  i just wanted to convey the idea of using subqueries to return the count values you were looking for.  `GROUP BY NAME` is also necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE1>'2012-01-01' AND DATE2<'2012-12-31' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN (DATE3>DATE2 AND CURDATE()>DATE2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number2 
FROM T1 GROUP BY name
```